# BLE communication data type

Tags: json, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, bluetooth-gatt

Bluetooth newbie here.
Is there a best practice among the data type used for BLE communication?
In my case I am setting up a ESP32 that acts as Server: it has a single Characteristic with a Notify property, so it repeatedly sends data to all the Clients once they connect (a raspberry pi as Client, in my case).
Right know the data exchanged is just bytes (based on the [*Neil Kolban* *"BLE_notify"* Arduino example](https://github.com/nkolban/ESP32_BLE_Arduino/blob/master/examples/BLE_notify/BLE_notify.ino)) but it would be great to send Strings or better **JSON data**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send in whatever format you want if you use custom characteristic uuids. Although generally BLE data transfer is slow so you'd better make your data as compact as possible. Json might not be the best option here. I've not heard of anyone sending json over BLE. Some binary format is what's generally used.